# Fluent Ribbon: Specify position of contextual tab groups?

Tags: wpf, fluent-ribbon

In the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite, is there a way to make the contextual tab groups show up first instead of last? I was using an older build and had a contextual tab group for the first three tab items, and two more with no group. Downloaded and built the newest source; the tabs in the group are now on the right end. I want them to show in the same order as I have them specified in the xaml. I don't see any obvious properties that would allow me to specify the order.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one had an answer to this, and I just got a Tumbleweed badge for it :), I decided to post my solution, which was to modify the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite code. I modified `ArrangeOverride` in the `RibbonTabsContainer` class. This caused the Grouped tabs to be rendered before the ones not in a group:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Positions child elements and determines
        /// a size for the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="finalSize">The final area within the parent 
        /// that this element should use to arrange 
        /// itself and its children</param>
        /// <returns>The actual size used</returns>
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            var finalRect = new Rect(finalSize)
                                {
                                    X = -this.HorizontalOffset
                                };

            var orderedChildren = this.InternalChildren.OfType<RibbonTabItem>()
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Group != null); // <==== originally .OrderBy

            foreach (var item in orderedChildren)
            {
                finalRect.Width = item.DesiredSize.Width;
                finalRect.Height = Math.Max(finalSize.Height, item.DesiredSize.Height);
                item.Arrange(finalRect);
                finalRect.X += item.DesiredSize.Width;
            }

            var ribbonTabItemsWithGroups = this.InternalChildren.OfType<RibbonTabItem>()
                                               .Where(item => item.Group != null);

            var ribbonTitleBar = ribbonTabItemsWithGroups.Select(ribbonTabItemsWithGroup => ribbonTabItemsWithGroup.Group.Parent)
                                                         .OfType<RibbonTitleBar>()
                                                         .FirstOrDefault();

            if (ribbonTitleBar != null)
            {
                ribbonTitleBar.InvalidateMeasure();
            }

            return finalSize;
        }
```